# beginner woes togglebutton arrays?

Tags: android, arrays, togglebutton

just started messing with the android sdk and need to think about optimizing my code.
ive searched and done tutorials but it just doesnt click for togglebutton arrays.

this is an example of what i have, you can see if i have say 128 buttons its going to get messy.
i also need to know the checked state of the button

```
my activity class
private ToggleButton seqButton1;
private ToggleButton seqButton2;
blah.....
private ToggleButton seqButton128;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

seqButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
seqButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
....blah
```

any help or point in the right direction would be ace ta

edit:
this is my new code that crashes

```
    package trkrPkg.trackr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TrackerActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

     @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Toggle Button:" + buttonView.getId() + " is checked: " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_toggle_container);

        for (int i = 0; i<128; i++) {
            ToggleButton tgl = new ToggleButton(this);
            tgl.setId(i);
            tgl.setOnCheckedChangeListener( this);
                layout.addView(tgl); 
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about to access togglebutton arrays this way: http://goo.gl/0dkNg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the ToggleButtons dynamically instead of declaring them in xml and

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    //..

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Toggle Button:" + buttonView.getId() + " is checked: " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_toggle_container);

       //..
       for (int i = 0; i<128; i++) {
        ToggleButton tgl = new ToggleButton(this);
        tgl.setId(i);
        tgl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            layout.addView(tgl); 
       }
       //...
    }
}//end class
```

Comment: thanks, this is what im after but the app just crashes. can you see anything wrong here.

Comment: it's quite difficult to diagnose why your program crashed without seeing a stack trace. did you create a linear layout called my_toggle_container in your layout xml?

Comment: thanks Damian i got it working, not sure what it was :s. i need to check if the button is checked and the most efficient way would be if ToggleButton tgl = new ToggleButton(this);
this created an accessable array of tgl. how could i do that? cheers

Comment: Rather than store an entire array of toggle buttons, you could probably do ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton)findViewById(28); //e.g. if you wanted to check togglebtn #28. And the tgl.isChecked();

Comment: ok thank you that causes ut to crash too :( inside a timertask im doing this ToggleButton tgl = (ToggleButton)findViewById(xBtn); if (tgl.isChecked()){do dtuff.. whats wrong? thanks

Comment: Perhaps a better solution is to have an array of booleans to store the checked state e.g. boolean[128] values = new boolean[128]; Then in your onCheckedChange method you can do: if (isChecked) values[buttonView.getId()] = true;